# Selecting two names based on ID stored in different table

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

Suppose I have two tables:

- Table 1: tasks with columns (id, authorId, assigneeId)
- Table 2: employee with columns (id, name)

`authorId` and `assigneeId` in Table 1 are referenced to the `id` column in Table 2.

What is the way to select Task ID, Author Name and Assignee Name (Assignee name defaults to 'null' if no assigneeId is present) from these two tables?

I am not sure how to start, thus making it difficult. Could anyone give a hint on how to start the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join twice:

```
select t.id, e1.name as author_name, e2.name as assignee_name
from tasks t
left join employees e1 on e1.id = t.author_id
left join employees e2 on e2.id = t.assignee_id
```

Comment: Thank you. For the sake of completion (print null if assigneeId is blank)

select t.id, e1.name as author_name, IFNULL(e2.name,'null') as assignee_name

from tasks t

left join employees e1 on e1.id = t.authorId

left join employees e2 on e2.id = t.assigneeId;